# Wait function for andengine?

Tags: android, andengine, wait

I'm programming a game by andengine.I created a loop with Runnable.And I wanna  create a wait(seconds) function.
for example there are 10 small pictures as sprites.they are moving from (100,100) to (100,400) by MoveModifier with 1 second rate.but I want: the program will wait x seconds between 5 and 6 picture.? –How can i do that?

Comment: for example there are 10 small pictures as sprites.they are moving from (100,100) to (100,400) by MoveModifier with 1 second rate.but I want: the program will wait x seconds between 5 and 6 picture.?

Answer (score 7):

Another approach to the delay modifier is to use a TimerHander. The timer handler will perform a function you define after the specified delay time. A nice feature of teh TimerHandler as opposed to using an android Handler is that the TimerHandler will pause and resume when the game Engine pauses and resumes.

Here is the TimerHandler used in the Snake game included in the andengine examples:

```
/* Make the Snake move every 0.5 seconds. */
        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.5f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                if(SnakeGameActivity.this.mGameRunning) {
                    try {
                        SnakeGameActivity.this.mSnake.move();
                    } catch (final SnakeSuicideException e) {
                        SnakeGameActivity.this.onGameOver();
                    }

                    SnakeGameActivity.this.handleNewSnakePosition();
                }
            }
        }));
```

== Update ==
In spite of this being the accepted answer, I believe the answer by Nicolas Gramlich below is better. Of course being Nicolas Gramlich, he didn't really document his answer, but expects you to go look it up in the encyclopedic "Andengine Examples". So here is how you would use a DelayModifier:
The Delay modifier is an ideal choice for what is described above, because you are already using a move modifier, and so chaining modifiers together is simple.

Here's an example from andengine examples (*author: Nicolas Gramlich) 
https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/EntityModifierExample.java?r=2b26f37114e50616bfcbb8e292e20988efd1acd6

The part to examine is :

```
new SequenceEntityModifier(
    new RotationModifier(1, 0, 90),
    new AlphaModifier(2, 1, 0),
    new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 1),
    new ScaleModifier(2, 1, 0.5f),
    new DelayModifier(0.5f),
    new ParallelEntityModifier(
                    new ScaleModifier(3, 0.5f, 5),
                    new RotationByModifier(3, 90)
    ),
    new ParallelEntityModifier(
                    new ScaleModifier(3, 5, 1),
                    new RotationModifier(3, 180, 0)
    )
)
```

You can see that you can put a delay between any two modifiers with a delay modifier.
However, the delay modifier only works if the delay is part of a modifer, rather than a function you wrote. In that case, the TimerHandler solution will do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

DelayModifier.

(Sixteen chars)

Comment: yeah, that's what I said too - then it got converted to a comment because it was considered a trivial answer, lol